# Data Scraping a Locally Stored HTML File

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
    <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Programming</font></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <col align='right' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>A1000</font></td>
    <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>D.Rogers</font></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

It is locally stored. I am trying to figure out how to data scrape "Programming","A1000" and "D.Rogers. How can I do this using Java and Jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can read the contents:

```
for(Element e : doc.select("td font")) {
    String text = e.text();
    // do something with text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in the post:

```
String localHtml=" <table cellspacing=\'0\' border=\'0\' width=\'100%\'>\n"+
        " <col align=\'left\' />\n"+
        " <tr>\n"+
        " <td align=\'left\'><font color=\'#FF0000\'>Programming</font></td>\n"+
        " </tr>\n"+
        " </table>\n"+
        " <table cellspacing=\'0\' border=\'0\' width=\'100%\'>\n"+
        " <col align=\'left\' />\n"+
        " <col align=\'right\' />\n"+
        " <tr>\n"+
        " <td align=\'left\'><font color=\'#000000\'>A1000</font></td>\n"+
        " <td align=\'right\'><font color=\'#008000\'>D.Rogers</font></td>\n"+
        " </tr>\n"+
        " </table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(localHtml);

System.out.println(doc.select("font[color=#FF0000]").text());
System.out.println(doc.select("font[color=#000000]").text());
System.out.println(doc.select("font[color=#008000]").text());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Programming
A1000
D.Rogers
```